# Assembling i386 code on x86_64

Tags: assembly, x86, offset, gnu-assembler, i386

The following code does not work as expected:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.arch i386
.data
hello_world:
.ascii "Hello world!\n"
hello_world_end:
.equ hello_world_len, hello_world_end - hello_world
.text
.global _start
_start:
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, hello_world
mov edx, hello_world_len
mov eax, 4
int 0x80

mov ebx, 0
mov eax, 1
int 0x80
```

When ran through:

```
as test.s -o test.o
ld test.o -o test
./test
```

It outputs nothing. When I change the line:

```
mov ecx, offset hello_world ; added offset
```

It works fine. I tried compiling the original code with `--32 -march=i386` and linking with `-m elf_i386` but it still outputs nothing.

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-38-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 13 13:22:43 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My guess is this happens because the memory model isn't flat like in i386. Can I emulate this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about the memory model.

In gas syntax `mov ecx, hello_world` means **a read from memory address** `hello_world`, as can be confirmed by checking the disassembly done with ndisasm:

```
00000000  BB01000000        mov ebx,0x1
00000005  8B0C25D4104000    mov ecx,[0x4010d4]
0000000C  BA0D000000        mov edx,0xd
00000011  B804000000        mov eax,0x4
00000016  CD80              int 0x80
```

What you want is to **store the memory address** of `hello_world`. In gas the way to accomplish that is `mov ecx, offset hello_world`, as can be confirmed from the disassembly:

```
00000000  BB01000000        mov ebx,0x1
00000005  B9D4104000        mov ecx,0x4010d4
0000000A  BA0D000000        mov edx,0xd
0000000F  B804000000        mov eax,0x4
00000014  CD80              int 0x80
```

By the way, another way to do load the memory address into a register is [`lea`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/lea.html)`ecx, hello_world`.

Some other assemblers (such as NASM and YASM) have different syntax, and this difference may cause confusion, as can be illustrated with a small table:

```
gas                           NASM/YASM                ndisasm disassembly
mov ecx,hello_world           mov ecx,[hello_world]    mov ecx,[0x4010d4]
mov ecx,[hello_world]         mov ecx,[hello_world]    mov ecx,[0x4010d4]
mov ecx,offset hello_world    mov ecx,hello_world      mov ecx,0x4010d4
```

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Assembling with `as test.as -o test.o` doesn't cause any problems, but linking with `ld test.o -o test` fails: `test.o(.text+0x8): error: undefined reference to '$hello_world'`.