# Assembly commands LEA/LDS/LES

Tags: assembly, x86, command

What is the difference between the following commands: `LEA`, `LDS`, `LES`? I searched for the answer but I'm not very clear on it. From what I understood `block1` should be equivalent to `block2`.

```
.data
  str1 db 'My first string. $'
  str2 db 'My second string. $'
  ptr_str1 dd str1 
  ptr_str2 dd str2
.code
  _block1:
  mov AX, @data
  mov DS, AX
  mov ES, AX
  lea SI, str1
  lea DI, str2

  _block2:
  lds SI, ptr_str1
  les DI, ptr_str2
```

... but when I print `str1` and `str1` using the following macro, the second block doesn't return the expected results.

```
print MACRO param
    lea DX, param
    mov AH, 9
    int 21h
ENDM
```

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339813 answer/help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`lea` means **Load Effective Address**. So `lea SI, str1` sets `si` to the offset of `str1`. The correct memory addressing syntax used by `lea` and other instructions depends on the assembler used, some assemblers want `lea si,[str1]`.

`lds` and `les` do something completely different compared to `lea`. `lds` means **Load pointer using DS** and likewise `les` means **Load pointer using ES**. In practice, `lds SI, ptr_str1` sets `ds` and `si` based on the values stored in the memory address `ds:ptr_str1` (the syntax is `[ds:ptr_str1]` in some assemblers).

So, what these instructions do in your code:

1. `lea SI, str1` sets `si` to point to the address of `str1`. This seems perfectly OK.
2. `lds SI, ptr_str1` sets `si` to `'My'` (0x794d in hexadecimal) and also sets `ds` to `' f'` (0x6620 in hexadecimal). Note that x86 is a little-endian architecture. `ds` is the default segment from where the pointer value is read using `lds` and `les`. So instead of loading the string address to `ds:si`, the first 4 bytes of the string are used as an address that is loaded into `ds:si`. I assume this is not what you wanted to do.
3. `les DI, ptr_str2` sets `di` according to the value stored in 0x6620:ptr_str2 (`ds` is the default segment for most x86 instructions, and currently `ds` has the value 0x6620) and also sets `es` according to the value stored in 0x6620:ptr_str2+2. Probably this is not what you wanted to do.

Comment: I personally never write `lea si,str1` (or similar, for `mov`, `push`, etc.) but always either `lea si,[str1]` (possibly with `dword ptr` and friends if it is not clear) or `mov si,offset str`, that is, I always add either the brackets or the `offset` operator, to disambiguate. This is because when you do neither, assemblers differ from each other: some add the brackets, some the `offset` (especially irritating with `mov` and friends). But good explanation, +1.

Comment: @mirabilos `dword ptr` and friends are irrelevant for `lea` and do not affect encoding, as only the memory address matters for `lea`. The difference of memory addressing syntax of different x86/x86-64 assemblers is quite annoying as the exactly same syntax may have different meaning in different x86/x86-64 assemblers and thus may cause bugs if assembled with a different assembler. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984788/assembling-i386-code-on-x86-64/14984887#14984887

Comment: I know that it's the same for lea, but still, teaching good style in one go may be not unimportant.