# x86-64 Intel syntax of operands

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86, x86-64

I am trying to get a (reasonably) complete picture of x86(-64) assembly going in my head.  So x86 assembly is a rather simple syntax at a large picture view; we have in EBNF-ish:

```
Assembly ::= Line+
Line ::= Label?: Operation Operand? Operand?
```

That is assembly is a list of lines, where each line is a (maybe) label, followed by an operation and 0, 1, or 2 operands.  A reasonably complete list of the operands can easily be found in the Intel manual for example.

It's the operands that I'm struggling with -- making sure I've got all the cases.  The Intel manual, while it does discuss syntax, it often mixes it in to the discussion of the semantics, and it makes it hard to assess whether your picture is complete/correct.  For example, it took awhile to find why

```
add [gs:rdi+0x49],bl
```

is correct.

"Within an assembler, the segment override is generally handled with a colon “:” operator."
Vol.1 3-21.  Still, I had to see examples to know exactly the syntax of using the colon operator, and never found it in the manual (yet!!).

My question is: are there any places/projects that give precisely the syntax of operands that are allowed in x86(-64)?

Below is my first attempt: Feel free to correct, improve, and add wherever I have messed it all up.  I use an EBNF-ish syntax, ? means 0 or 1, [X-Y] means 1 character from the characters in the range of X and Y, | means or.

Define registers:

```
Reg ::= (E|R)?[A-D]X | (E|R)?(S|D)I | (E|R)?(B|S)P | R815(W|D)? | 8BitR | FPU
       | MMX | SSE | AVX | EFLAGs
8BitR ::= [A-D]L |[A-D]H | (S|D)IL | (B|S)PL | R815B
815 ::= 8 | 9 | 1[0-5]
FPU ::= ST[0-7]
MMX ::= MM[0-7]
SSE ::= XMM[0-7] | MXCSR
AVX ::= SSE | XMM8 | XMM9 | (X|Y|Z)MM1[0-9] | (X|Y|Z)MM2[0-9] | (X|Y|Z)MM(0|1)
        | (Y|Z)MM[0-9]
```

Segments:

```
Seg ::= (C|F|G)S
```

Data Types:

```
Data ::=  Byte | (D|Q)?Word | Real(4|8|10)
```

... Did I get these right?  All of them

Operands:

```
Operand ::= Reg | Memory | Data Reg | Data "PTR" Memory | Data? Literal
Memory ::= "[" (Seg":")? Reg ("+"Literal)? "]"
Literal ::= 0xInteger
```

Have I missed anything?  References are encouraged!  If anyone finds this useful, I will make the parser available.

Comment: Consider that syntax is determined by assembler, not by CPU

Comment: @Bushmills: I'm not sure what you mean.  There are different syntaxes one could use to abstract over the exact binary sequences that get exectuted.  Intel defines a syntax, and I am trying to make sure I understand how Intel views the syntax of x86-64.

Comment: Intel suggests one possible set of syntactic rules, but it is up to the implementation of specific assemblers to respect them or introduce different syntactic rules. See for example difference between Intel and AT&T syntax, both used for x86-64, depending on the assembler you use, an ever popular source of joy and entertainment for those required to work with both types of sources.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the title of the question.  I am interested in Intel syntax for x86-64.  This is a point that gets tricky for me.  Ultimately, x86-64 isn't a programming language, it's an architecture or hardware that allows programs to run.  However, in my view, Intel syntax for x86-64, should describe a programming language that I can compile into the binary file that runs on x86-64; it is this programming language's syntax that I want to nail down.

Comment: I don't think this `[8-15]` means what you think it means.

Comment: What about `AH`, `BH`, `CH`, and `DH`?

Comment: @DwayneTowell: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html.  It should mean the character class comprised of 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15.

Comment: I did not take EFlags as an allowable operand.  Perhaps I am wrong?  Nor segments.  Also: Control registers are CR0 to CR4, Debug registers are DR0 to DR7, test registers are TR3 to TR7 and the protected mode segmentation registers are GDTR (Global Descriptor Table Register), IDTR (Interrupt Descriptor Table Register), LDTR (Local DTR), and TR.

Comment: Not all assemblers that generally follow Intel syntax (rather than AT&T syntax) allow segment prefixes inside square brackets, at least MASM wants them outside square brackets if I remember correctly. But if you wish your parser to handle specifically Intel's own syntax (and not NASM, YASM, MASM, FASM, TASM etc.), that's a lot easier task than try to make it handle all Intel-based syntaxes. Anyway, it should handle 3 operands too, like this: `imul r15,[rbx+rcx+0xdeadbeef],dword 0x2badcafe` (in YASM/NASM syntax, I don't have an Intel assembler at hand now).

Comment: Also, the literally same syntax (exactly same ASCII or Unicode representation) can mean different things in different assemblers. See the last table of my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984788/assembling-i386-code-on-x86-64/14984887#14984887 . The presented differences in memory addressing between NASM/YASM on the other hand and GAS (using Intel syntax) is just a small part of all differences between all assemblers that use some Intel-based syntax; usually each assembler has its own syntax to some extent.

Comment: There are also fpu, mmx, sse, avx instructions with accompanying registers, control and debug registers, instructions with 4 operands, more segment registers than what you have listed and they can be used as operands too, effective address syntax allows for `[base+index*scale+displacement]` but not all combinations thereof, operand and address size overrides, `far`,`near`,`short` specifiers, `lock` and `rep` prefixes and presumably even more stuff that I can't think of right now.

Comment: @nrz: Thank you for the comment.  You are right, the segment prefixes inside the brackets were coming from one disassembler, whereas it's outside the brackets in another.  Is there an actual Intel syntax, or are there just ideas behind Intel syntax, such as operand ordering?  Suppose I chose a particular disassembler, is there a specification of it short of reading their parser?

Comment: @Jester: Thank you.  I was trying to steer away from listing all the operations of assembly.  I'm not sure I have every single operation covered.  I am using http://x86.renejeschke.de/ of instructions along with the Intel manual to double check.  I was under the impression that in x86-64 CS,SS,DS,ES are disabled.  I would be extremely grateful if you could provide more information or references on the effective address syntax.

Comment: The intel manual
http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf
 discusses prefixes on Vol. 2-A, 2-1, but it's a bit tough to make out.  The operand and size override prefix are 66H and 67H respectively.  I have no idea how they would look from the description given in the manual.

Comment: @JonathanGallagher, read the link you provided more carefully. `[8-15]` means `[8-1]|5`. That is all the charaters inclusive from `8` upto `1`, which is likely to mean none; OR the single character `5`. What you want is `(8|9|1[0-5])`.

Comment: @DwayneTowell.  Right thanks; I was a bit informal on that.

Comment: I've made many changes based on these comments thank you.

Comment: x86 & x86-64 are far from orthogonal architectures and there are many limitatations for allowed operands, eg. with REX prefix you can't use `ah`, `ch`, `dh` or `bh`. `in` and `out` only accept immediate port number or `dx` and the data must be in `al`, `ax` or `eax`. In bit shifts and rotates, if the number of bits to shift is not fixed (immediate), it must be in `cl`. The signed immediate must always fit in 32 bits, except in `mov` it can be 64 bits. There is also `rip`-relative addressing. There are two different instructions named `movsd`... Validating x86-64 assembly is not trivial.